# How to get list of ids from pagination query of the current page?

Tags: laravel

I have 1 pagination query for every:

```
$pagination_query = Table1::...->paginate(100);
```

then I have a second query that needs to use the list of ids from the pagination query:

```
$second_query = Table2::whereIn('id', $list_of_ids_from_pagination_query);
```

How can I get the list of ids only from the paginated page so that I get 100 ids and not thousands of ids which will end up in too many bound variables error?

Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this .

```
$ids = Table1::...->paginate(100)->pluck('id');


$second_query = Table2::wherein('id', $ids);
```

Comment: Thank you that does work. From some reason it didn't work for me when I tried something similar

Comment: then try something like this, i am not sure
 `$first = Table1::...->paginate(100);`
`$ids = collect($$first->items())->pluck('id');`
`$second_query = Table2::wherein('id', $ids);`